# How to insert a query into SQLite with an autoincrementing value for each row

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Suppose I am inserting the following queryset into a new table in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE queryset_cache AS 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over () AS rowid, * FROM mytable ORDER BY product;
```

Is it possible to either:

- Set the `rowid` as auto-incrementing PK in sqlite from the insert, or;
- Exclude the rowid and have SQLite auto-add in an autoincrementing primary key for each inserted record.

How would this be done?

Currently, without that when I do the insert, the rowid is not indexed.

Comment: What is the issue here? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @LudovicFeltz do an insert that has rowid as an autoincrementing field. https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: So this field auto-increment... why are you trying to set a value?

Comment: If you create the table first, you can add all of the values except `rowid`, then let it increment itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowid` is already there.  You can just do:

```
CREATE TABLE queryset_cache AS 
    SELECT t.*
    FROM mytable t
    ORDER BY product;
```

You will see it if you do:

```
SELECT rowid, t.*
FROM queryset_cache;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=777f8c2b21fc6fbbcf760a65a7f29a94) is a db<>fiddle

Comment: thanks, does sqlite automatically add an auto-incrementing (sort-of hidden) field on every table it has? I was under the impression that when creating the new table it would use the `rowid` from the old table, but I guess I am (fortunately) wrong in that.

Comment: Automatically added. Not copied from the original table.

Answer (score 0):

Auo increment should solve this. Documentation here:

https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Create source table:

```
create table sourceTable (oldID integer, data TEXT);
```

Add source data:

```
insert into sourceTable values(7, "x");
insert into sourceTable values(8, "y");
insert into sourceTable values(9, "z");
```

Create target table with auto-increment:

```
create table target(newID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, data TEXT);
```

Move data from source to target:

```
insert into target select null, data from sourceTable
```

Comment: Please no link only... can you post an answer with some code? Will remove my downvote after you edited your answer....

Comment: @Mark -- could you show in sql how that would be done on the insert? Or are you suggesting running an alter table statement after the insert?

Comment: Edited answer for clarity with example.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a table like:

`create table employee (empID integer, name text , address text);`

insert data into this table.

create a table in which you want to insert employee table data:

`create table newEmployee (newempID integer PRIMARY KEY, name text , address text);`

copy data to newEmployee table:

`insert into newEmployee select * from employee`

(`select * from employee`) to copy all the columns